# Pandas Dataframe.to_csv - insert value of variable into beginning of csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.8.5 Pandas 1.1.3

I'm using the following to loop through json files and create csv files:

```
import os
import glob
impot pandas as pd

def stuff():
    results_list = []
    for filepath in glob.iglob('/Users/me/data/*.json'):
        filename = str(filepath)
        file = open(filepath,"r")  
        data = file.read()
        df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'main')
        df.to_csv(filename + '.csv')
        file.close()
        results_list.append(data)
    return results_list
```

The format of the resulting csv files fits my requirements exactly without having to pass any additional params to the `to_csv` method - when viewing the csv file in Excel, row 1 is the keys as the headers, and column 1 is the index numbers.  Exactly what I need.  Cell A1 is blank.

One final step that I need to accomplish is to write the `filename` variable value to the csv file.  Ideally I'd like to put it in cell A1, if possible.  Can I accomplish this solely with `to_csv` or am I going to need to get into `csv.writer` world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the index name for that purpose:

```
df.rename_axis('somename').to_csv()
```

Comment: I figured there had to be an easy way with Pandas.  Thank you.  For anyone reading this, I simply changed my `df.to_csv` line to `df.rename_axis(filename).to_csv(filename + '.csv')`. This did the trick.